# add nodes with attributes changes

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AAA>
    <BBB CCC="it is aatr 1" DDD="it is attr 2">
</AAA>
```

I want in my c# application to add several BBB nodes than my xml will look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <AAA>
        <BBB CCC="it is aatr 1" DDD="it is attr 2">
        <BBB CCC="it is another attr 1" DDD="it is another attr 2">
        <BBB CCC="this is something else 1" DDD="this is something else 1">

    </AAA>
```

any suggestion of code?

Comment: What does this have to do with node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `DOM` (System.Xml) and `Linq to XML` api.

Linq to XML

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
 XElement ele = new XElement("BBB");
 ele.SetAttributeValue("CCC", "text1");
 ele.SetAttributeValue("DDD", "text2");
 doc.Root.Add(ele);
 doc.Save(file);
```